# How do i hide text in wordpress post

Tags: wordpress

I want to have tags on my wordpress post but i don't want to display them under the post excerpt. I want it in a way that hiding of the tags does not effect the google search result.

Comment: hidden text and links won't help your google rating: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353?hl=en

Comment: Like I say the kids "I want" doesn't get people much. Post a question and anything you tried. SO is for problem with code, not a wishlist :)

Comment: did you do your own research? what have you found? what have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a 'please make this for me' site

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the PHP function called `strip_tags()`

As an example:

```
<?php
    echo strip_tags(the_excerpt());
?>
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/strip_tags)